# Improving of java code - scale image

Tags: java, image, frame, scale

I am still pretty new to Java and tried to find information about how to include a picture in a frame. 
Some pictures have the right size and fit in my screen, however other definitely have to be scaled to make them fit in. 
So far I got this, is there a way to improve it and scale the picture down? For example half of the size it has now? What do I have to change in the code?

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

class DisplayImage {

    public static void main(String avg[]) throws IOException
    {
     DisplayImage img =new DisplayImage();
    }

    public DisplayImage() throws IOException
    {
        BufferedImage img=ImageIO.read(new File("C://Address.jpg"));
        BufferedImage ret = new BufferedImage(32,32,BufferedImage.SCALE_FAST);
        ret.getGraphics().drawImage(img,0,0,32,32,null);

        ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(img);
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(200,300);

        JLabel lbl=new JLabel();
        lbl.setIcon(icon);
        frame.add(lbl);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the question is, but `new BufferedImage(32,32,BufferedImage.SCALE_FAST);` is wrong: The last parameter should be the **type** of the image, for example, `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale an image with the following code:

```
image.getScaledInstance(-1, 25,
            java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```